# Duplicate Content

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

is there any way, to remove the duplicate content, produced by D7?

An Example:

You can reach a node with two URL's:

```
http://mysite.com/node/3
```

Or:

```
http://mysite.com/nodename
```

The same problem with taxonomy terms

From SEO view, this is very negative...

Is there any way, to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It's already handled for you, if you look at the source you'll see the `<link rel="canonical"` tag which lets search engines know which page to consider the 'original' content.

This is Google (and others) preferred method to handle this type of situation; there's more information on [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29624/how-do-i-make-a-page-available-via-only-a-single-url/29625#29625).

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from one URL to the other: use the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a simple module which:
>
> - Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
> - Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> - Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> - Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the 'unclean' method.
> - Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private aliased node's.
> - Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the alias with any combination of case.
> - Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the globalredirect_admin module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled into the module.